# html5 videos not playing in chrome and safari in stage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a problem in playing html5 videos in chrome and safari in stage.Local its playing all browsers.its playing after 10 to 15 mints in chrome and safari in stage
.but in stage firefox playing currcetly.Pls help to me .Here i have pasted my code.

```
<video id="mgtvideo"  width="268" height="194" control="controls" >
     <source id='mp4video' src="<?php echo base_path()?>sites/default/files/videos/Srinivas_Balasubramanian.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source id='oggvideo' src="<?php echo base_path()?>sites/default/files/videos/Srinivas_Balasubramanian.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    <source id='webmvideo' src="<?php echo base_path()?>sites/default/files/videos/Srinivas_Balasubramanian.webm" type="video/webm" />
  </video>
```

mp4 size:20mb
ogg size:5mb
webm size:7mb

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: http://html5video.org/

Sidenote: HTML5 doesn't require the solidus ( / ) to close self-closing tags anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently completed a mobile app with HTML 5 video and, strangely, I found the order in which the videos are placed in the  tag mattered. In order to get cross browser compatibility I specified the formats in the following order

1. MP4
2. WebM
3. OGV